# Derivate of matrix conjucation

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

Consider the map from $GL(R,2)$ which sends a matrix $X$ to the map ($Y\mapsto XYX^{-1}$). This is a map smooth map $f:GL(R,2)\rightarrow End(GL(R,2)$ so we should be able to calculate its derivative.

Calculating the derivative at the identity applied to some $Y\in T_eGL(R,2)$ we want to calculate $d_I(f)(Y)$. We can pick a curve $\gamma$ with $\gamma(0)=I$ and $\dot{\gamma}(0)=Y$. Then $d_I(f)(Y)=\frac{d}{dt}f(\gamma)$.

I am not sure how to calculate this derivative. Because $f(\gamma)$ is a map sending $Z\mapsto \gamma(t)Z\gamma(t)^{-1}$. To calculate this do we need to take another curve in $Z$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, recall the following result:

> **Proposition.** Let $H$ be a square matrix of operator norm strictly less than $1$, then $I+H$ is invertible and
> $$(I+H)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^nH^n$$
> which is called Neumann's series.

**Proof.** Since $\|H\|<1$, the series in the statement is absolutely convergent, hence convergent and a direct computation shows that:
$$(I+H)\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^nH^n=I,$$
whence the result claimed.

**Remark.** This result shows that $\operatorname{GL}(E)$ is open whenever $E$ is a Banach space.

Now, carry the following computations:
\begin{align*}
f(I+H)(Y)&=(I+H)Y(I+H)^{-1},\\
&=Y(I+H)^{-1}+HY(I+H)^{-1},\\
&=Y+HY-YH+O(H),\\
&=f(I)+\ell(H)(Y)+O(H),
\end{align*}
where $\ell(H)\colon Y\mapsto HY-YH$ and notice that $\ell$ is linear, whence, $d_If=\ell$.